# Trying to pass data (a list) from client to server using FormData

Tags: c#, form-data

i have this class and the list that i want to populate

```
 public class ContentTemplateViewModel
    {
       public List<AttachmentDTO> TemplateFilesData { get; set; }
}
```

all the properties are inside this class

```
public class AttachmentDTO : AttachmentInfoDTO
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public int FileSize { get; set; }
}
```

Im trying to bring to my controller the ID and FileName

using this code

```
    var options = new FormData();
    let existingFiles = viewModel.get("entity.TemplateFilesData"); // holding the items
                    existingFiles.forEach((item, index) => {
                        if (item) {
                            options.append('TemplateFilesData[' + index + ']', item.FileName);
                            options.append('TemplateFilesData[' + index + ']', item.ID);
                        }
                    });
```

for some reason i get [0] : null , [1] :null
when i get the back to controller

Comment: Why did you tag this Java?

Comment: sorry someone else did this and i approved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can try to fix this issue:

1. Make sure that `viewModel.get("entity.TemplateFilesData")` is returning a valid list of `AttachmentDTO` objects. You can check this by adding a debug statement to print out the returned list.
2. Make sure that you are correctly appending the `ID` and `FileName` properties to the options object. You should use the `append()` method to add each property as a separate entry in the options object, like this:

   ```
   options.append('TemplateFilesData[' + index + '].ID', item.ID);
   options.append('TemplateFilesData[' + index + '].FileName', item.FileName);
   ```
3. Make sure that you are correctly accessing the `ID` and `FileName` properties of each `AttachmentDTO` object. Make sure that these properties have values and are not `null` or undefined.
4. Make sure that you are correctly handling the index variable in the loop. Make sure that you are using the correct syntax for accessing the elements of the `existingFiles` list, and that you are not attempting to access an index that is out of bounds.

Comment: jesus i forgot to specify when iterating (options.append('TemplateFilesData[' + index + '].ID')